# Maven repository's issue in Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I tried all the suggested solutions which found on Stackoverflow but didn't solve the issue with Maven repositories in Intellij IDEA. The problem is that I can't find needed jars in local repository, even if I update it. Central repository is impossible to be updated. Just for example: I use in web-app servlet api (jar is found in local repo but the version is 2.5), jstl and jdbc. If I don't create Maven project I just add all the external libraries to the project manually. But in the case of Maven-project I do not add nothing but try to create dependency through **Alt + Ins** when writing the class. Result - there are not needed jars in local repository.

What I tried:

1.Installed/deleted a couple of versions of Maven (The current is 3.2.2)

2.Defined local repository in settings.xml (the tag missed by default)

3.Updated local repository

4.Added dependency manually in pom.xml but IDEA didn't define it

Moreover, when I created a first Maven-project in IDEA according to web-app archetype it didn't have needed folders structure but started donloading the number of jars. Current version of IDEA is 13.0. If somebody faced such problem please help me to eliminate it.

Comment: so what happens when you run mvn install ? What messages do you get ?

Comment: Do you have a local maven repository?

Answer (score 0):

> But in the case of Maven-project I do not add nothing but try to
>   create dependency through Alt + Ins when writing the class. Result -
>   there are not needed jars in local repository

You actually have to perform an maven install, this downloads the jars from whereever to your local repository. Just writing the depenecy in pom, doesn't actually download them.

This is how maven works, nothing to do with intellij.

Comment: I built project in IDEA not in command line. You mean that when I build a project all the needed jars which are indicated in pom.xml will be loaded automatically? If yes how I can know the correct names of the libraries? Sorry for silly questions but I just started learning Maven tool. Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't work. See, I find javax.servlet jar at search.maven.org. Add dependency to pom.xml (<artifactId> tag), Maven starts updating its central repository... and it looks like endless process! File/Settings/Maven/Repositories - in the state of update of central repo is noticed "Error".

Comment: Might it be problem with Idea? I will try to build a project in command line